# Tokio execution of task in async manner

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

```
use tokio::task;
use std::thread;
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    for _i in 0..200 {
        task::spawn(async move {
            for _j in 0..1000000000 {

            }
            println!("{}",_i);
        });
    }
    for _j in 0..1000000000 {
        
    }
    println!("HELLO FROM MAIN THREAD !!!");
}
```

first thing that i understood is that tokio runtime uses only one thread for the execution of the tasks.
in this code example when i executed this code this code is getting executed in the pieces of  8.
why this is happening because if it is using only one thread it should only execute one task at a time ??

Comment: if your logic holds up, and  itcan only run 1 thing at a time, sequentially, what is the point of tokio? That would be not different from not using Tokyo at all. So I doubt your assumption is true.  It may use an event loop or virtual threads or other techniques to achieve concurenncy. The fact that it uses only 1 thread, doesnt mean alot.

Comment: *"tokio runtime uses only one thread for the execution of the tasks"* - That is incorrect. According to [the documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/attr.main.html), the default is the multi-threaded runtime with as many threads as your system has cores. Which in your case is probably eight.

Comment: Also be aware that using `tokio` for compute bound tasks as this is **not advised**. Tokio is meant for tasks that are IO bound and have `.await` points in them. For more information, read the [tokio tutorial](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial), especially the section *"When not to use Tokio"*. For introducing multi-threading in your program, use something like [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon/) instead.

Comment: #[tokio::main(flavor = "multi_thread", worker_threads = 10)]
sorry my bad, I have read tokio there we can use multi-threading in tokio but one thing I wanna ask is when we specify 10 worker_threads how those 10 tasks are getting executed parallelly ??
here event loop is doing context switching or what?
can u please tell me this thing in detail @Finomnis?

Comment: You would think it as having 10 different event loops.

Comment: To my understanding tokio is just like a big task queue. There is no preemption. But tasks can be paused (at `.await` points). Then, the task gets put back into the queue and the thread takes a different task. And all threads just do that continuously. I'm sure it's a little more complicated internally, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: You're blocking the executor. You must never ever do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are using [task::spawn](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/index.html) module of tokio. One of the main goals of tokio is managing tasks in parallel. Tokio tasks are not the same as OS tasks in a way that tokio-task management is more conscious of efficiency (e.g. by using cooperative multitasking model vs os-tasks preemptive model). So in your case tokio will pass tokio-tasks to tokio scheduler and aim to execute them as much in parallel as possible.

Now each simple task like yours is CPU bound - requires one core for execution. From what you are saying your code is executed in bunches of 8, which suggests your system's architecture - 8 core!